# Form to .txt with titles (variable names)

Tags: php

I'm saving the input of a form to a .txt file. I've got that part down like so:

```
$myFile = "files/".$fileid. '.txt';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
$comma_delmited_list = implode("\t", $_POST) . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $comma_delmited_list);
fclose($fh);
```

Since I have a lot of $_POST variables I'd like to have the name of the variable next to the value. So the optimal output would look like this:

`variablename = foo, variablename2 = bar` and so on.

Is that possible?

Comment: yes, but i really urge you to consider a database like MySQL.

Comment: if you must- loop at a `foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) ..` loop

Comment: This is possible, but painful, since you have to think of escaping all values too. Why not use a format like JSON or use phps builtin csv functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $arr[] = $k . ' = ' . $v;
}
$comma_delmited_list = implode(" ", $arr) . "\n";
```

**With escaping for safe restore:**

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $arr[] = preg_replace('~\t~', ' ', preg_replace('~=~', '', $k) . ' = ' . $v);
}
$comma_delmited_list = implode("\t", $arr) . "\n";
```

**With escaping for safe restore + "$_POST array":**

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $vArray) {
    if (!is_array($vArray)) {
        $vArray = array($vArray);
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($vArray as $v) {
        $arr[] = preg_replace('~\t~', ' ', preg_replace('~=~', '', $k . (count($vArray) > 0 ? $i++ : '')) . ' = ' . (string)$v);
    }
}
$comma_delmited_list = implode("\t", $arr) . "\n";
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: No it does not, since this produces some other output, not what the OP asks for.

Comment: no he  wants the post array key, which implode just does the values

Comment: You forgot to escape the values.

Comment: Well, you have to escape the characters that interfere with the separation characters you want to use. The OP used a TAB character, you use a blank. What if a key or a value contains that character?

Comment: Also you have to take care of values that are not of type string or have a magic function converting them to strings. Yes, not _that_ common, but certainly possible...

Comment: :-) But those are all details :-) You solution is correct, I upvoted.

Comment: It does indeed! Can this be modified to also account for Array $_POST variables like `$_POST['foo'][0] , $_POST['foo'][1]` etc. ? Currently it will just save it as "Array" in the text file. I'll accept the answer either way since the original question was answered correctly.

Comment: @Mvorisek Um.... Sorry, but.... "escaping" is _not_ simply removing characters that annoy you...

Comment: @user327685 LOL, interesting :-) Sure this can be extended for that case. You just have to add a switch for the type of value and then react accordingly.

Comment: Hm, that would leave all values in such array associate with the same key which is not correct and as said: the escaping strategy is, well, surprising...

Comment: @arkascha same keys fixed. I think the escaping is ok, if not, you can always use serialize($_POST) and simply do not care about escaping...

Comment: To escape a character such that it does not collide with some special control meaning that character is used for you have to define an escape sequence. There is no other way. Typically some "escape character" is used that precedes the character that is to be escaped to form the "escape sequence". Long story short: `\t` => `\\\t` Sorry I cannot give you more than a single upvote for your effort!